# Flexbox children not full width & height when using border on parent

Tags: css, flexbox

The following code (https://jsfiddle.net/mr6tLj0x/)

```
<div class="wrapper" style="width:200px;">
  <span class="" style="width:67%;" >67%</span>
  <span class="" style="width:33%;">33%</span>
</div>

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid gray;

            > span {
                padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;

                &:nth-of-type(5n+1) {
                    background-color: red;
                }

                &:nth-of-type(5n+2) {
                    background-color: orange;
                }
        }
}
```

results in [image]

As you can see there is some space to the right and bottom. Why do the children not take 100% width and height? I tried using `align-items: stretch;` on the parent and `flex-grow:1;` on the children, but it didn't help.

Comment: With which browser are you having this issue? In your fiddle, I can't see your problem. Maybe it also caused by something else that is not in the fiddle

Comment: Chrome Version 81.0.4044.122. It seems to be a chrome bug, it works in FF and Edge.

Comment: Well, I've updated Chrome to that version.. still, not visual bug. Are you seeing the issue even in the JSFiddle? Or do you see it only somewhere else (where the structure of the code it's a bit more complicated)

Comment: Oh.. what if you press CTRL + 0 ?  It should remove the zoom-in in the browser. If I have the zoom at 125%, I got the same problem as yours.

Comment: I can see it in my fiddle aswell as in my local development environment. Chrome incognito mode has the same problem.

Comment: What if you de-zoom the browser?

Comment: It seems to have something to do with the zooming, yeah. After zooming in to 90% and resetting it to 100% the problem only seems to appear on the right side now, not the bottom anymore. I just assume its something on my device and it should generally work. Thank yyou!